# Where and why add repositories on build.gradle

Tags: android, build, gradle, repository

When Android Studio creates a project, the top-level build file has two repositories definitions, one inside *buildscript* and another inside *allprojects*.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-    projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Where must I add another repository and why?

I think that repository inside buildscript is here to add the gradle plugin dependency, but I'm not sure...

Someone could clarify me, please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `buildscript` is for dependencies of your build files. You want to add a repository there if, for example, a task in your `build.gradle` needs a plugin that is not found in the standard Gradle distribution, like a gwt wrapper.

The `allprojects` is for dependencies needed by your application, like log4j, Guice, Guava and so on.

Also, be warned that using `mavenCentral` for retrieving dependencies is a bit discouraged, because if the network is down or if the project is removed from their repositories, you won't be able to build your project anymore

Comment: If you specify version of dependencies (with no `+`) and add `mavenLocal()` you can build offline. Ofcourse first build need to be online to download dependencies.

Comment: "Also, be warned..." - this just happened to me with [Hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo)