# Implementation of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to Android development. While using RecyclerView I found that we have to add RecyclerView as a dependency in Gradle.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc01"
}
```

My question is while implementing `recyclerview` it is compulsory to specify Maven in the repository because in 1 project I forgot to specify, and still everything is working fine.

Why is that so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where and why add repositories on build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077521/where-and-why-add-repositories-on-build-gradle)

Comment: Some other dependencies like Material Design also add RecyclerView to your project.

Answer (score -1):

the best and easiest way of doing is open your ActivityManin.xml file and in pallete option search for recyclerView , click on download button next to it ... drag and drop it into your screen this will ask you to add this into import click and this will automatically implement reyclerview dependency into  build.gradle file..